Flask App on AWS SageMaker Fails to Handle S3 Video Processing via Async Endpoint Invocation
I'm working on deploying a Flask application in AWS SageMaker, which is designed to handle asynchronous invocations. The application should fetch a video file from S3, process it using a face emotion prediction model, and then return the results. However, my setup isn't working as expected.
Here’s a summary of the steps in my process:
Async SageMaker Invocation: I trigger the invocation of my SageMaker endpoint using the invoke_endpoint_async method in my Python script, providing an S3 URI for a video file.
response = runtime.invoke_endpoint_async(
    EndpointName=endpoint_name,
    InputLocation="<s3 URI>",  
    ContentType="application/json"
)

Flask App (Deployed via ECR): The Flask app listens to POST requests at the /invocations endpoint, extracts the S3 URI from the request body, downloads the video file, processes it, and returns the prediction.
import os
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import source.face_emotion_utils.predict as face_predict
import boto3
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)

# Set up S3 client
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

@app.route('/ping', methods=['GET'])
def ping():
    return jsonify({'status': 200})

@app.route('/invocations', methods=['POST'])
def faceInvocations():
    try:
        # Extract the JSON payload
        payload = request.get_json()
        s3_uri = payload.get('InputLocation')

        if not s3_uri:
            return jsonify({'error': 's3_uri is required'}), 400

        # Parse bucket name and key from S3 URI
        bucket_name, key = s3_uri.replace("s3://", "").split("/", 1)
        filename = key.split("/")[-1]
        file_path = os.path.join('/app/input_files', filename)

        # Download the file from S3
        s3.download_file(bucket_name, key, file_path)

        # Process the file (predict emotions)
        prediction = face_predict.predict(file_path, video_mode=True)

        # Clean up temporary file
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            os.remove(file_path)

        return jsonify({'prediction': prediction})
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error: {str(e)}")
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)

What I Expect:

The SageMaker endpoint should receive the S3 URI from the async invocation.The Flask app should download the video file, run the emotion prediction, and return the results.

Problem:
The invocation fails, and I receive errors in the Flask logs. It seems like the S3 file isn't being properly downloaded or processed. Here are some logs:
INFO:root:Entered faceInvocations function
INFO:root:S3 URI: <s3 URI>
ERROR:root:Error downloading file: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found


and also I can see logs upto this point INFO:root:Created directory
What I've Tried:

Ensured that the S3 URI is valid and the file exists.
Verified that the IAM role attached to the SageMaker endpoint has s3:GetObject permission for the S3 bucket.
Checked the Flask app code for any errors in handling S3 URIsand able to get results with docker
Printed the S3 bucket name and key in the logs to make sure they are correctly parsed.

Questions:

Why is my Flask app unable to download the video file from S3, even though the S3 URI seems correct?
Are there any issues with how I’m handling the S3 URI in the Flask app?
Is there something specific to SageMaker async invocation that I am missing when passing the S3 URI?

